# Systems of linear equations: solving by addition

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have not understood this question. it confused me a lot. I have tried to solve it but the solution was senseless.

$$\begin{cases}
3x + 4y - 5 = 2x + 3y - 1\\
6x - 2y + 2 = 4x - 3y - 5
\end{cases}$$

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**
First turn the top and bottom equations into standard form, so you end up with a system that looks like this.

$$\begin{cases}
Ax + By  = C\\
Dx + Ey = F
\end{cases}$$

This can be done by combining the $x$ and $y$-terms on the left and moving the constant terms to the right. Then solve this "normal-looking" system using addition.

Comment: @user22634 You are welcome!